# Variable length arrays and static declaration in c

Tags: c

Why can't variable length arrays in C be declared as static? 
For example, this declaration is not allowed:

```
static char str1[lengthOfaString];
```

Comment: C99? What is the error? Paste `lengthOfaString` declaration please

Comment: Because you cannot determine the lenght of a string in a static context.

Comment: Because static *storage duration* means the object exists for the entire life of the program, including before any non-constant expression -- such as one used as an array length -- is evaluated.  Thus, the length of a static array needs to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @DavidIsla `lengthOfaString` is an `int` variable that holds a length of another string

Comment: Read comments above please. Can you declare `lengthOfaString` as `static const int lengthOfaString = 250;`?

Comment: @DavidIsla No I can not declare it as a `static const int`. It is the length of a randomly chosen string.

Comment: so...@JohnBollinger gave you the answer +1

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger Your explanation makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @DavidIsla for your comments

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you make your comment as an answer I think will be more clear and useful for other people.

Comment: @DavidIsla This does not change anything. It still is a variable. C is not C++!

Comment: @DavidIsla: More precisely, even with `static const`, the name of `lengthOfaString` is not a constant expression (even though a compiler may be able to evaluate it at compile time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When applied to a local identifier, the `static` keyword specifies that the object designated by that identifier has *static storage duration*.  That means the object exists for the entire life of the program, from before the evaluation of any non-constant expression.

By definition, variable-length arrays have length designated by an expression that is evaluated at runtime, when control reaches the array declaration.  The system cannot provide for such an object to have static storage duration because it does not know the object's size until some time after the object must already exist.

Note also that all file-scope variables have static storage duration, and therefore VLAs cannot be declared at file scope at all.  Indeed, at file scope, the `static` keyword has nothing to do with storage duration; instead, in that context it specifies *internal linkage*.